# What do you need to do for the Magellan achievement?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

I've explored the entire map. I've played an earth map, and circled the world in a sub. I've played a Pangaea and circled the globe by land. I can't think what else could be needed to accomplish this one.

Comment: This achievement *was* bugged. People only have begun to achieve it since the October steam patch.

Comment: Can you load up a saved map where you've discovered every square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The achievement is bugged. Look at [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/938528-sid-meiers-civilization-v/56890706) on GameFaqs to see the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having to go to another site for the solution, here it is.

To fix the Magellan achievement bug, navigate to your steamapps folder and drill down to:

`steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\Assets\Gameplay\XML`

Open GlobalDefines.xml in notepad

Find:

```
<Row Name="CIRCUMNAVIGATE_FREE_MOVES">
<Value>0</Value>
</Row>
```

Change the 0 in the  tags to 1.

Comment: Just be aware that this solution changes the rules of the game. You then get additional moves for the circumnavigation.